# how to install discord.js to your node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

i've been following a guide

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5kG0bI08EQ
```

In that guide they `use npm install discord.js` in command prompt and got a success, however when i do it. i got error like this

```
> ref@1.3.2 install D:\Discord\node_modules\ref
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Discord\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Discord\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v6.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:ref@1.3.2 ref@1.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:ref@1.3.2 Exit status 1
D:\Discord
`-- discord.js@9.3.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Discord\package.json'
npm WARN Discord No description
npm WARN Discord No repository field.
npm WARN Discord No README data
npm WARN Discord No license field.
```

Can anyone help me why i cant install it

Inside D:\Discord i have a folder named discord.js and the content are from `https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/`

his result:
[image: his result]

Comment: It says it couldn't find Python … so install Python?

Comment: Windows installs are also covered by the FAQ: http://hydrabolt.github.io/discord.js/#!/docs/tag/master/file/general/FAQ

Comment: both mine and the youtuber got python error, but mine failed to install while he's success. as for guide that you post, i tried to read but nothing seems relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to successfully install discord.js with voice support [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) is required. To install node-gyp on windows the easiest solution is to simply run 

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

then try the installation step again. If it fails try 

`npm install -g npm`
 
and restart your computer.

That said from the error provided it seems you are attempting to install discord.js v6 which has not been updated in a very very long time and may no longer function at any level. The discord api is constantly changing and it may be a good idea to update to something like 8.1 which is the last release backwards compatable with code writen for 6.0

Comment: The strange thing happen, before i read your comment, i tried to make a simple response bot and somehow it works. hmm, you said that i had to install the 8.1, but at my command there are no version number typed, so how do i know if its 8.1 or 6.0 or even newer?

Comment: @Neolitz ahh, you can install 8.2 using `npm install discord.js:8.2 --save` only leave in the --save if you have a package.json