# How can I import discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I import discord.js?

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('API_KEY');
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- C:*************\bot.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kalar\Desktop\JavaPr\JS_Bot\bot.js:1:17)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [ ←[32m'C:\*******************\bot.js'←[39m ]
}
```

the stars are just directories.
thanks for answering

Comment: Srry if you guys think this is bad i just got js today

Comment: go to your console and run `npm i discord.js`

Comment: You have to actually install external modules through npm (node package manager) in your terminal

Comment: and don't share your bot's key in public someone might edit your bot without your permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install an npm package, run this command:

```sh
npm install discord.js
# Or
npm i discord.js
```

This installs discord.js in `node_modules` and adds it to the `dependencies` field of your `package.json`.

I recommend reading [‘Installing Node.js and discord.js’ on the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/#installing-node-js).

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
```

This error means that it cannot find the module `discord.js`. It is possible that you haven't install the module. This can be because of two things:

1. **You didn't install it in the correct directory.**
   To fix this, try installing the module at your home directory, `C:\Users\kalar\Desktop\JavaPr\JS_Bot` for your case.
2. **You haven't installed the module yet.**
   Installing an npm package can be done easily, there are two options in doing it, try following the instructions below:

---

### Using `npm install <module>`

Run the following command in your home directory (where your bot.js is located), in this case `C:\Users\kalar\Desktop\JavaPr\JS_Bot\`.

```
npm install discord.js
```

If you happen to have a package.json as well, try this code to automatically append to your `dependencies` in `package.json`:

```
npm install --s discord.js
```

---

### Manually adding it in your `package.json`

If the above method didn't work, then, try to manually add to your `package.json` the `discord.js` module with version `^12.3.1`, which is latest as such:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1"
  },
```

You can change it to any version you want. Then, run the following command in the home directory  `C:\Users\kalar\Desktop\JavaPr\JS_Bot\` again:

```
npm install
```

---

If you still require more guidance, try checking out these guides:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Installing Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/#installing-discord-js)
- [how to install discord.js to your node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699596/how-to-install-discord-js-to-your-node-js)

Comment: Yeah thanks for the suggestion but i found out how i forgot to put a json file

Comment: Just do `npm init` and it should create a `package.json` for you, then you can add the `dependencies to that.

Answer (score 0):

To install discord.js via npm, type this into the console: `npm install discord.js`, or you can do `npm i discord.js`. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
```

This error means that it cannot find the module `discord.js`. It is possible that you haven't install the module.

Do this in terminal:

```
# npm init -y
# npm i discord.js
```